# execution time: woocommerce loading large dataset but needs filtered on the SQL side instead of script

Tags: php, mysql, woocommerce, filtering

I am running the latest woocommerce with PHP. I built backend portal from scratch using angularjs and custom PHP stuff on the "portal" which is private.

on a daily basis, I pull orders from woocommerce that is filtered fetching only status=processing however there are certain dates that we have using custom plugins for the customers to select their delivery dates, those dates resides in post_meta table hence theres SO MANY post_meta to load for each order.

example. We have 4 slots that falls on specific hours only on the current day (not yesterday not tomnrrow) and we have pages that shows a full list of orders following those slot hours but it also filters out so many stuff such as date, time, items, how many items ordered, cost, and we do have flags for scammers and bs, such as location, ph nbr and email checks, frequent customers count, reward systems, etx etx.

it has gotten so large that on a daily basis I am loading like 60-100 data at once but the script filtering out the data is consuming the time taken to load. if theres only 10-20 orders. thats fine but more than 30 will lag.

IM starting to find ways to look on the server side filtering it on SQL to save time in execution.

any idea or pointers that would help me.

it has to do largely with woocommerce orders on load but im running this script outside of wp region because I am using a standalone portal that I built that is designed to pull woocommerce orders and users. nothing more.

hope one can help out. cheers!

Comment: code executes like this when running the order screen

(start script)
while
fetch order object
if row(date) == date given
 collect customer data
run customer filters
check if first timer
check if large order
check if order is exchange
check if there are flags (scammer etx)
fetch customer address
fetch order details
check if any errors
render json output
write to file (end script)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the question. I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help folks understand the case you are trying to solve.